# Is there a way, using discord.py to send emojis without adding to their id number

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I send a message to discord, I constantly reach the character limit. This is due to having 3-20 emojis which all take up 25+ characters. I only want to send to one discord server so conflicting names isn't really the issue. Is there a way to send emojis without their id, thus reducing each emoji to a mere 5-10 characters.

I'm aware that you can send two messages, but I'd prefer to avoid this as it can get somewhat clunky.

Thanks :)

Currently I am just putting "<:EMOJINAME:emojiIDNUM>" as I have no idea how to solve this. They are custom server emojis.

Comment: Show the current method you are using.  Also, are these standard emojis, or are they custom server emojis?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to do so, as in the API (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Many people have tried this before (including myself), but the author of discord.py hasn't implemented something like this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use the "ID" of the emojis as they are all unique after you posted them.

If you want to use standard emojis you can have a look at https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html. Just copy and paste the emojis.

But if you want to use emojis which are not from Discord you can post the emoji somewhere and add a `\` to get the unicode/shorter "version" we can call it. This you copy and paste, but then you must not delete the message. Mostly the emoji must be on the server.

For a Discord emoji:

```py
:white_check_mark: = :white_check_mark:
\:white_check_mark: = ✅
```

For a Unicode emoji:

```
:close: = :close:
\:close: = <:close:741224892984197120>
```

Adding this to your code should help to reduce it.